# Jekyll - Rouge does not work in my custom theme

Tags: jekyll, rouge

I am making my own theme in Jekyll, and I wanted to use syntax highlighting.

For this I did:

1) Install `rouge` and `kramdown` in my Gemfile

```
gem 'kramdown'
gem 'rouge'
```

2) Update my `_config.yml`

```
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
```

3) Write some code in my post

```
{% highlight javascript %}
$(".myClass").on("click", function(){...});
{% endhighlight %}
```

But I am still not getting any highlighting.

Why is that? Do I need to include an specific `css` file in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible you forgot to install the gems locally. You shouldn't need to add the stylesheet but do check your browser console for any errors.

You should also be able to export a base stylesheet and extend it as needed:

```
rougify style base16.solarized.dark > css/syntax.css


<link href="/css/syntax.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: You conflicting styles!

Comment: Indeed, Bootstrap is conflicting with rouge (weird), but even after deleting it, I got no padding on the box. https://pasteboard.co/Hvbg0J5.png

Comment: Well, I can add the padding myself. The other problem was not conflict with bootstrap. The problem is that now to mark code, I have to use ``` instead of `{% highlight XXX %}`

Comment: You should be able to use both. I prefer ``` though because it is the same on GH comments, descriptions etc :) Is the issue solved?